# Geocoding gem for Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, geocoding, mongoid

Is there a geocoding gem similar to acts_as_geocodable for Mongoid? So far as I can tell all geocoding gems seem to be built for ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoder seems to work with mongoid http://www.rubygeocoder.com/
There is also a nice screencast here http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder.

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like GCoder https://github.com/heycarsten/gcoder if you are using google.

If you want callbacks like acts_as_geocodable you can extend your model to use this lib.